# How to filter a list attribute with a filtering list in JPA?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0

In my application, a course has a list of tags as its member field. There is no @OneToMany annotation for the list. And I can successfully retrieve the tags. It's storing as blob in my MySQL db.

I like to filter course with only those tags while doing pagination in my repository. I have

```
Page<Course> findAllByTagsIn(List<String> tags, Pageable pageable);
```

And JPA is not happy with it

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [rr] did not match expected type [java.util.ArrayList (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [rr] did not match expected type [java.util.ArrayList (n/a)]
```

The Course class

```
@Entity
public class Course {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long courseID;
    private String courseName;
    private String courseDescription;
    private String courseNumber;
    private int courseEnrollment;
    private String accessCode = generateAccessCode();
    List<String> tags = new ArrayList<>();
    // getters and setters and other methods omitted.
}
```

That's Exception I got, anyone got an idea how to work around this.

TIA.

Comment: can you post your `Course` class ?

Comment: Please try using `Page<Course> findByTagsIn(List<String> tags, Pageable pageable);`

Comment: `org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter value [rr] did not match expected type [java.util.ArrayList (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [rr] did not match expected type [java.util.ArrayList (n/a)]` Same error

Comment: @Laurainmar Could you please provide the full stack trace.

Comment: @Laurainmar  Could you please also provide a simple example of data that you store at your `tags - blob` field. Why you decide to use so exotic solution?  I am wondering that it works for retrieving the tags at all :)